# How do I loop through files in npm in a way that works on Windows & linux?

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I'm trying to run a single command (jshint), on multiple files. My package.json contains

`"lint": "jshint *.js **/*.js"`

However this fails miserable on Windows. On Windows the syntax to [iterate on multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615/how-to-loop-through-files-matching-wildcard-in-batch-file) is

```
 for %%f in (*.in) do (
            echo %%~nf
    )
```

Is there a simple, platform-agnostic way to run a single npm script (e.g. jshint) on multiple files?

(I'm interested in the general solution. There's a references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7682611/11236) to using node-jslint instead of jshint, which does support multiple files ... but IMO jshint >> jslint).

Answer (score 1):

I'm also not aware of a platform agnostic way to loop in the shell.

However, a platform agnostic solution to running a single *npm-script* on multiple files with [jshint](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/), as per your example, is to:

1. Utilize [cli-glob](https://github.com/jayzawrotny/cli-glob) to find the `.js` files.
2. Pipe the results/paths from the globbing pattern to a custom utility node script.
3. Then within the node script:

   1. Read the paths piped to `stdin` using nodes [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) module.
   2. Create an `Array` of each path and subsequently convert that to a `String`.
   3. Run the `jshint` executable, (including the `String` of all paths), using nodes [`child_process.exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) module.

Whilst this solution is not particularly *"simple"*, the following gists demonstrate this process:

---

#### npm-script

```json
"scripts": {
    "jshint": "glob \"src/js/**/*.js\" | node .scripts/jshint.js"
},
```

***Note*** *cli-glob*, *(added to package.json)*, obtains the paths and pipes them to *jshint.js*.

---

#### jshint.js

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var readline = require('readline');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: null,
    terminal: false
});

// Normalise path to local jshint executable.
var jshintExec = ['.', 'node_modules', '.bin', 'jshint '].join(path.sep);

var paths = [];

function jshint(paths) {
    var command = [jshintExec, paths].join('');
    exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (stdout) {
            console.log(stdout);
        }
        if (stderr) {
            console.log(stderr);
        }
    });
}

rl.on('line', function(srcPath) {
    paths.push(srcPath);
});

rl.on('close', function() {
    jshint(paths.join(' '));
});
```

***Note***

Line 16 reading:

```js
var jshintExec = ['.', 'node_modules', '.bin', 'jshint '].join(path.sep);
```

The script assumes `jshint` has been installed locally and added to the `"devDependencies": {}` section of the `package.json`. I.e. Its pointing to the local `jhint` executable found in the `node_modules/.bin` folder and not the globally installed one.

If your preference is to run the globally installed `jshint` then change line 16 to:

```js
var jshintExec = 'jshint ';
```

*Personally, having it installed locally is the preferred option IMHO for this scenario!*

---

#### Multiple globbing patterns

Your example provided includes multiple glob patterns.

> `"lint": "jshint *.js **/*.js"`

One limitation of [cli-glob](https://github.com/jayzawrotny/cli-glob) is that it doesn't accept multiple glob patterns. So one workaround is to do something like this:

```json
"scripts": {
    "jshint": "npm run jshint-a && npm run jshint-b",
    "jshint-a": "glob \"*.js\" | node .scripts/jshint.js",
    "jshint-b": "glob \"**/*.js\" | node .scripts/jshint.js"
},
```

Yeah, not particularly terse - but works!

Answer (score -1):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't loop in the shell in a cross-platform way.

However, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/catw and do something like this:

```
catw "**/*.js" | jshint -
```

`catw` will expand the glob(s) itself without relying on the shell and write the files to stdout. `jshint -`  will read from stdin. The pipe (`|`) works cross-platform.

Comment: `catw` no longer exists

Comment: Updated link; package is unmaintained, though.