# standardjs + gulp: How to treat source files as one?

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, standards

I'm really excited about having just introduced [Standard JS](https://standardjs.com/index.html) into my workflow. My web project uses [Gulp JS](https://gulpjs.com/) to watch changes and report any syntax errors.

Similar to another question I've [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628009/jslint-with-multiple-files). Standard JS works great for singular files. However, I tend to break my scripts into separate files for legibility and sanity reasons.

This results in various `is not defined`, `is assigned a value but never used`, and `is defined but never used` warnings. If I manually concatenate all the files, those warnings are not thrown.

I understnad this is just looping through all the files individually:

```
standard --fix "dev/scripts/**/*.js"
```

...but I wondered if there were any flags, settings, or other resources I could use to treat all the files as one?

[gulp-standard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-standard) seemed promising at first glance, but still has the same problem. It's important to me that the `--fix` flag is used to modify the local development files. I don't want to rely on editor plugins (Atom/Sublime) that need to be installed locally for each developer.

I'm surprised to see so few reports on this. Either no one else fragments their code; or I'm missing something far more fundamental in the way I code.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

## 1. Use a module bundler. Explicitly `import` or `require` shared variables.

This makes the external variables that are referenced by each file explicit. So, you can't reference a variable until you've required it in the current file.

[`browserify`](http://browserify.org/) is a nice, simple bundler to use to get started with this npm-centric development model.

### Example:

```
var myVar = require('./lib/my-module.js').myVar
console.log(myVar)
```

## 2. Use a `/* global myVar */` comment.

This makes it clear to readers of the file (and the StandardJS tool) that you are intentionally referencing a variable external to this file.

### Example:

```
/* global myVar */
console.log(myVar)
```

## 3. Reference the variable as a property of the global.

### Example:

```
console.log(window.myVar)
```

## 4. Concat the files, then run StandardJS on the built file.

It sounds like this approach worked when you tried it. It's not a bad idea to just always run it like that.